# Insider Preview image on Dragon Board fails with Speech Synthesizer

Tags: windows, iot, universal

I have been working on a UWP(Universal Windows Platform) on Minnow Board that uses Microsoft's STT synthesizer and it's been working great with the release version of Windows IOT(10.0.10240.16384). After purchasing Dragon Board and getting an insider preview which is the only IoT version available for it, the app stops working - continuous speech recognition goes idle at the beginning.

I tested it with the Windows Universal App Samples from Github that includes TTS app. I recreated the same bug on the Minnow Board with Insider Preview installed.

**How Found:**
Installed Insider Preview on Dragon Board (v10.0.10556.0)
The app failed to recognize speech because the process goes idle

**Configuration Details:**
Dragon Board with Windows IOT v10.0.10556.0
Also happens on
Minnow Board with Windows IOT v10.0.10556.0

**Steps to Reproduce:**
Install an Insider Preview Image on the Dragon Board
Download Microsoft's app samples from https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples
Launch the app called SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis
In includes Continuous Dictation Tab which works with the Release build, but no longer works on the latest Insider Preview
After pressing Dictate button, the dictation just stops right away

Comment: Faced same problem. With the build 10586, speech recognition does not work on RPi2 anymore. When I revert back to old 10240, it works like charm. If I run same program on PC, it works but not on IoT device. Hope, they may resolve in next build. :)